# Converting Str to Datetime which extracted from Beautifulsoup

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup

I am extracting the date from the article and want to store into MySQL database.

```
html = urlopen('https://www.horizont.net/medien/nachrichten/spot-remake-das-ist-der-neue-pick-up-spot-mit-fahri-yardim-und-christian-ulmen-178272')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

pub = bs.find('span', {'class':'PublishDate_date'}).get_text()
```

O want to convert the str to datetime but nothing working so far? 
Any idea how to solve this problem?

This is how output shows

```
16. Oktober 2019
```

Comment: How is this related to pandas?

Comment: he probably was using the pandas datetime methods

Comment: because i thought we need to use pandas library to convert it into datetime @horace

Comment: The output doesn't fit any of the python [datetime format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) so I don't think there'll be a clean way to convert it via standard libraries.

Comment: is it just for this page or will you do this with other pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to parse only dates from that website, which is in German, you can use the [`dateparser` module](https://dateparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

Installation:

```
pip install dateparser
```

Sample output:

```
>>> dateparser.parse('16. Oktober 2019')
datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 16, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful. \